# how to insert a html tag from .ts file

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have an attribute called type in data and i want to display icons specific to those types which are available in my icon css

```
setdata() {
    if(this.queryModel.type === ''){ 
      this.queryModel.type = '*';
    }
    this.getTableData().subscribe(data => {
      for(let key in data ){
        if(data[key].type=="user")
        data[key]["img"]= <i class="ias-icon ias-icon-user_thin"></i> ;
        else
        data[key]["img"]= <i class="ias-icon ias-icon-favorite_outline_thin"></i>;
      }
      this.setTableData(data);
      this.sortdata = data;
    });
  }
```

how to give an html icon tag in img attribute.

Comment: `data[key]["img"]= <i class="ias-icon ias-icon-user_thin"></i>;` You can't do this in angular, instead, let the function return some value and use `ngSwitch` or `ngIf`

Comment: Or if you want to store a string, surround the html with quotes `data[key]["img"]= '<i class="ias-icon ias-icon-user_thin"></i>';`

Comment: Can you add the html code?

Comment: i'm sending this data[key][img] to another component from which everything is directly displayed so is there any other way for me to send the icon directly ?

Comment: as far the html code its like i'm using ngfor in table row to display all the values so if i change for this i will not be able to display other attributes present in data